# How to use Spring Data Neo4j Repository save method with specific id?

Tags: java, neo4j

I'm using [Neo4j](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j) to create graphs. The below codes is an example for spring data Neo4j. I can save a node entity when no id property value is provided.

But how to save a node entiry with a specific id property value?

**Model Class:**

```
@Data
@NodeEntity
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String title;

    @Relationship(type = "ACTED_IN")
    private List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

**Repository Class**

```
public interface PersonRepository extends Neo4jRepository<Person, Long> {

    @Query("MATCH (n:Person {name:{name}}) RETURN n")
    List<Person> findByName(@Param("name") String name);
}
```

**Controller Class**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/person")
public class PersonController {
    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    @PostMapping("/save")
    public Map save(@RequestBody Person person) {
        Map resultMap = new HashMap();
        String code = "200";
        String msg = "success";
        // It can save success when no id property value is provided
        Person savedPerson = personRepository.save(person);
        resultMap.put("code", code);
        resultMap.put("msg", msg);
        resultMap.put("data", savedPerson);
        return resultMap;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried it successfully and can be easily done provide the "id" should be

> **String not Long**

Domain/DAO class:

```
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = Neo4JCustomIdStrategy.class)
 String id;
```

Repository Class:

```
@Repository

public interface PersonRepository extends Neo4jRepository<Person, String>{
}
```

And lastly, custom implementation of Strategy:

```
public class Neo4JCustomIdStrategy implements IdStrategy {

  @Override
  public Object generateId(Object entity) {
    return String.valueOf(entity.hashCode());
  }
}
```

The library I am using is spring-data-neo4j

Comment: Which library do you use,Spring Data Neo4j or Neo4j-OGM ?

Comment: The library I am using is spring-data-neo4j

Comment: I have tried it. It works. But the custom id property must be **LONG** type ?

Comment: Must be of type String, it doesn't work with type Long

Comment: Pleasure to help you out @Michael.